# Gradle sync completed with some errors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-signin

I am trying to add a google services plugin for google sign in.

Syncing the project after adding some lines in the project level and the app level `build.gradle` files results in the following:

> Gradle project sync completed with some errors

Accompanying message :

> Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If
>   using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   /home/vin***/Documents/Projects/F/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your project folder in windows explorer and open gradle folder in it.
2. Go to wrapper folder, there you will find gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Its contents would be something like

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Change the distributionUrl's end to 2.10... or whatever your warning says.

Go to Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Gradle => choose Use default gradle wrapper

Comment: My `distributionUrl` is already what you mentioned. It's not working.

Comment: did u try Tools > Android > Sync project with gradle files? can you try it once?

Comment: See the last line of my answer once and try it please.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have set in you `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

You have to options:

1. Change your `distributionUrl` in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
2. Change your build.gradle to an specific version like

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
   ```

In my case I use the second one, because like you, I use `gradle-2.4`.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: My `distributionUrl` and `build.gradle` version are already set to what you've mentioned. But Android Studio gives the same message.